# Class.forName returns an inner class?

Tags: blackberry, reflection, classcastexception

I'm writing a BlackBerry application which loads XML from a web server and generates objects based on the XML tags. These generated objects all implement the same interface, and are cast to this interface before use.

I've recently implemented menu items in the Messages app which, when selected, launches my app and pushes a screen. This screen is expected to get XML from the server and create objects like normal - and it works, provided it's not called from the menu item.

When called from the menu item, I receive a `ClassCastException` for only one type of object on the page. Similar objects are cast fine, and this object is cast fine when it's not being instantiated from the menu item class.

Here's where it gets interesting: In the debugger, when `Class.forName` is run on the XML tag normally, I can highlight the resulting `Class` object to see

```
  Class my.package.location.ClassName$MyAppName
```

When I call it from the menu item and get a class cast exception, the `Class` object appears as

```
  Class my.package.location.ClassName$XMLReflectionTest
```

I suppose this is why the cast fails, even though both seem to refer to my object.

`XMLReflectionTest` is not a class or subclass in my project, but Google only returns two search results, neither of which are even somewhat related.

It works fine everywhere else, and even for different classes using the same method! **Why would calling `Class.forName` using the same class string return two "different" classes, based on *where* it's called from?**

I've looked into ClassLoaders, which I could possibly be the issue, but then why would the issue only occur for one class, and not all of them?

Comment: Can you simplify the code down to one or two classes that demonstrate the issue, and post that here?

Comment: I've found another solution to my problem (I ended up using global events, which make more sense, anyways), but I'm still curious about the reason. I don't have the exact code anymore, though.

Setting it up was relatively simple. Create an ApplicationMenuItem with code in run() which calls a function in another class in your project which calls Class.forName() to create an object, then compare that object to an object created in that other class.

But as I said, it worked for some objects. You know, the more I think about it, the worse the idea was in the first place.

Comment: Steven, for me it sounds like you have incorrect XML. Everything is pointing to this - package name and inner class name. I would suggest first check it.

Comment: I've tested the same XML file in other situations, and it doesn't cause any problems. I specified "inner class name" because even though Class.forName is called with the same string, the debugger states the object has (is?) a different inner class.

I don't know very much about inner classes; I'm assuming that when Eclipse puts a '$' after a class then lists another class, it's referring to an inner class. Shouldn't all inner classes have an "is a" relationship with their outer class? (Is my terminology wrong? I'm referring to "MyAppName" and "XMLRefelectionTest" as inner classes of ClassName)